Como pudo capturar iframe src python
estoy haciendo este switcheo:
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/ html / body / div[1] / div / main / div / div / div / div / div[3] / iframe'))"""

pero no se como capturar el src o el #document de la página.
Alguien que me pueda ayudar por favor.
Gracias


¿Hay 2 divs antes del main (en la imagen no se alcanza a ver) ?

¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour].Por favor no publiques código o mensajes de error/trazas de pila en imágenes, publica directamente el texto del código, el texto de los errores y los stack traces. Esto hace que sea menos complicado, para quien quiera ayudarte, investigar sobre el tema y hacer sus propias pruebas/adaptaciones al código, al escribir una respuesta y de esa forma aumenta tus posibilidades de encontrar la ayuda que buscas. Un saludo.
